# How to change the "Read more" text?

Tags: read-more

I am using this code in `functions.php` to so it will show on the front of my site and show the read more, but the read more is not showing, your help would be appreciated.

```
 function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . ' '
           . __('<br/><br/> Read More') . '</a>';
    }

    add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Here is my site demo link: http://visionedc.com/2015/news

Comment: You'll have great luck referencing the Codex, particularly the [Customizing the Read More](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) area.

Answer (score 1):

The `excerpt_more` filter only handles the linked text - not the link itself.

Try:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '<br/><br/>Read More';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Answer (score 0):

I advises you to use this simple function in your functions.php

```
function read_more_modif(){
    $readmore = "make your custom text her" ;
    return '<div class="lireSuite"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">"'.$readmore.'</a></div>'; 
    } 

add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', ' read_more_modif' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in functions.php:

```
function develop_custom_excerpt_more($more) {
     global $post;
     // edit here if you like
     return '...  <a class="excerpt-read-more" href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="'. __( 'Read ', 'domain_name' ) . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post->ID ) ).'">'. __( 'Show more &raquo;', 'domain_name' ) .'</a>';
 }
 add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'develop_custom_excerpt_more' );
```